# Show Pageblock as popup on page

Tags: visualforce

I want to show page block as a popup when a button in clicked.

```
<apex:pageBlock><apex:commandButton value="Test Popup" /></apex:pageBlock><apex:pageBlock id="pb1"></apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: This link should help you out http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-modal-dialog-box/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following UI elements:

- jQuery UI Dialog: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
- ExtJS Window: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Window

both can be used easily by either referencing a div container as content or loading an external page as an iframe. So using the div or apex:outputPanel just fill it with your pageBlock content somewhere in the page, hide it and call your dialog to display it, like (jquery example):

```
//don't forget to include jquery and jqueryUI as static resources

<apex:commandButton onclick="openDialog();" value="Open Dialog"/>    

<div id="dialog" style="display: none;">
    <apex:pageBlock>
    ... // your pageBlock content goes here
    </apex:pageBlock>
</div>

<script>

    function openDialog(){
       $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    }

</script>
```

There are lots of options to tweak dialogs and ExtJs has the advantage that the libraries are already available as salesforce uses them heavily.